# How to remove Mail.app's constant confirmation to send mail after hitting send on Touch Bar

Tags: mail.app, high-sierra, touch-bar

I've been using the Touch Bar send mail shortcut a lot for sending email and it used to work well in Sierra:

[image]

Now, after upgrading to High Sierra, when I hit send, it asks for confirmation:

[image]

The whole purpose of Touch Bar is to provide contextual shortcuts to get the job done quickly. Why on Earth does hitting send button on Touch Bar (it's not the case with regular clicking) ask for a confirmation? If it's for people accidentally hitting send instead of esc, I'm sure they can come up with a better solution as this practice kills the whole convenience of Touch Bar's usage in this sense. Is it only me who is having this issue?

Comment: If it turns out you don't get proper answers because there is no way to change that exact native functionality, I think you might be able to get around it with [Better Touch Tool](https://www.boastr.net/). I don't have touch bar, but since I do have BTT, I checked out the touch bar options and it totally seems like you could use it to place a custom icon in the touch bar, that triggers a shortcut or a script.

Comment: I don't use Mail app either, but I'm thinking there must be a shortcut that'll send the email without prompts. Note that BTT has predefined action called `Send shortcut to specific app`, which maybe won't do you any good here, but is a way to do something like this when the target app is not active.

Comment: @Joonas thanks Joonas, I'll have a look at it. I wish there was a native way of achieving this, but still, it should do the trick.